# MC34063A ferrite bead

Tags: converter, ripple, ferrite

The converter works in the inverter mode and gives an output of -5V.
I present a diagram based on the documentation. I want to eliminate the output voltage ripple with a ferrite bead. Unfortunately, I don't know which bead to choose. Can anyone can tell me how to calculate the parameters of a proper bead (formulas and equations welcome).

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ferrite beads do nothing at this frequency. Get a better regulator: MC34063 is the worst possible pick for low noise purposes, which I guess you are after.

Comment: You need either a gigantic iron powder inductor, an LDO or as Tim said, a better regulator.

Comment: Are you talking about the small oscillation at a few 100 Hz, or about the super faint bursts at several 10 kHz ?

Answer (score 1):

Voltage ripple at a few 100 Hz is not addressed by ferrite beads. The latter target noise snubbing at the MHz-GHz range.

This low frequency ripple is typically addressed by feedback correction of the voltage regulator. If you regulator does poorly, you can follow it up with a linear regulator.

Comment: Thank you for response. 
Ok, so I will use LC filter. However I am still interested in how to properly select the correct ferrite bead, apart from the converter.
Suppose I have 100 MHz ripples from a microcontroller. What calculations should be made to choose the right ferrite bead?

Comment: @grandzello Even LC filters will require enormous values to do much below 1 kHz. An active regulator is much more suited. For bead selection, first determine the minimum signal bandwidth you need to pass through the filtered line. For power, this is usually <<MHz. Then select a bead which becomes lossy (i.e. resistive) at the lowest possible frequency that still permits your desired signal bandwidth. For power, "ultra-high-loss" beads can be used, which become resistive above approximately 5 MHz. Also consider the DC current through the bead and pick a bead with according DC current spec.

Answer (score 1):

Switching power supplies do not like to work well without a minimum load. In this case, they operate in discontinuous mode, which results the higher output noise. Try to load it until it starts to work continuously. If this requires too much load current, choose a higher value of L1. In continuous mode, the output can be filtered better, e.g. with a subsequent LC filter.